# How to update UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm buidling an app in which I want to allow my user to filter an array of data (employees) based on one criteria (company they work in). I want to do this using UISegmentedControl. 
I also want to allow my user to edit the array of companies ad any time, and when he/she does that, the UISegmentedControl needs to be updated (in order to filter the employees properly), depending on the amount of companies in the companies array.

I have been trying this for a while but I can't figure out how to do this.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: By updating the `UISegmentedControl` are you implying setting its new selectedIndex, updating its color scheme, loading different set of buttons and resizing it or even something else?

Comment: loading a different set of buttons it is! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all the segments

```
[self.segmentedControl removeAllSegments];
```

insert new ones

```
  for (NSString *title in self.employees.reverseObjectEnumerator) { //reverse to keep the ordering
    [self.segmentedControl insertSegmentWithTitle:title atIndex:0 animated:NO];
  }
```

The frame will be updated automatically, but you might want to recenter the segmented control

```
  self.segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(floorf(self.view.frame.size.width - self.segmentedControl.frame.size.width) / 2,
                                           floorf(self.view.frame.size.height - self.segmentedControl.frame.size.height) / 2,
                                           self.segmentedControl.frame.size.width,
                                           self.segmentedControl.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one `UITableView` and reload table contents when selected index of the `UISegmentedControl` changes.

#### Example

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{ 
    if(_segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {
        return [List1 count];
    }
    else if (_segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
    {
        return[List2 count];
    }
    
    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
           
    if(_segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
    {
        List1Object *sampleObject = [List1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        
        // Configure the cell...
    }
    else if(_segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex==1) 
    {
        List2Object *sampleObject = [List2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        
        // Configure the cell...
    }

    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)segmentedControlIndexChanged
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

This should point you in the right direction.